# How of should I migrate my Smart Contract?

Tags: truffle, contract-design, truffle-migration, ganache

I am developing a scraper which scrapes data and puts it on ethereum blockchain(ganache for dev) every week. So as to put this data onto the blockchain should I migrate my smart contract each time I am updating the data?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Migration is a one-time deployment event, like launching a ship. Afterwards, the contract is deployed forever.

It's a general question, so I'll give a general answer. Usually, the contract should be designed to accept and record the important information every week.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How should I pass the data from my scrapper to the smart contract?

Comment: You build a contract with functions that accept input.